# To me, a strange linker error in C++, MSVC/Visual Studio 2017; DLL implicit linking

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Below code that compiles by itself. 
It produces "libtea.dll" and the .lib to be used to link libtea.dll with another object (executable or another dll )

As a U*/Linux old g++ user, I really can't undestand in MSVC (Windows), why tstring::word::operator()(), implemented in the tstring.cc file  cannot be shared (resolved) at link time on the "client" project, while the rest of the tstring class members are all accessible... ??

P.S.: Please, don't judge the too common name lib"tea"...  Because I like drinking tea a lot! :)

```
    //...
[libtea.h]
#pragma once

#ifdef TEA_EXPORTS // Well defined
#define TEA_API __declspec(dllexport) // <-- Compiling the lib
#else
#define TEA_API __declspec(dllimport) // <-- Compiling the client project
#endif
[EOF libtea.h]

// ...
[tstring.h]
#pragma once
#include <libtea.h>
#include ...
//...
class TEA_API tstring{
//...
    struct word { // x64: 48 bytes;
        string::iterator begin;
        string::iterator end;
        string operator ()(); // ---> LNKC2019 ...external unresolved...

        using array_t = std::vector<word>;
    };

    struct cword { // x64: 16 bytes;
        const char* begin;
        const char* end;
        string operator ()(); // -----> LNKC2019 ...external unresolved...

        using array_t = std::vector<cword>;
    };
//...
[EOF tstring.h]


Client(-test) program main:
#include <tstring.h>
//...
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int { // c++ 14 : why not ?  :-)

    tstring str;
    str << "libtea.dll: size of tstring::word=[%d] <> std::string:[%d] <> tstring::cword[%d]\n";

    str.arg(sizeof(tstring::word)).arg(sizeof(string)).arg(sizeof(tstring::cword));
    cout << str();
    tstring::cword::array_t words;
    size_t sz = str.cwords(words, "", true);
    cout << "words: " << sz << ":\n";
    for (auto& w : words) {
        cout << "[" << w() << "]\n"; // tstring::cword::operator()(void): cannot be resolved....LNKC2019 ...external unresolved...
    }

    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope the code shows clearly what I face against MSVC ...
Thank you very much for your attention :)

Comment: You don't state what error you are getting?

Comment: `#define TEA_API __declspec(dllexport) <-- Compiling the lib` I suspect you don't have these statement verbatim there, no? Use comment to highlight that.

Comment: Anon Mail : LNKC2019. It's "embedded" as comment in the code...:)

Comment: user0042: Thank you for noticing. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! No! 
I didn't know that I have to apply "TEA_API" attr to inner structs as well !! 
Client project is compiling and linking now.

Sorry. ***I am learning***....

```
class TEA_API tstring{

//... 

    struct TEA_API word{
        string::iterator begin;
        string::iterator end;
        string operator ()();

        using array_t = std::vector<word>;
    };

    struct TEA_API cword {
        const char* begin;
        const char* end;
        string operator ()();

        using array_t = std::vector<cword>;
    };

    //...
```

output:

```
libtea.dll: size of tstring::word=[48] <> std::string:[40] <> tstring::cword[16]
tstring::words : token_separators:"\"'();,%<>=+-*/:.":
words: 26:
[tstring]
[.]
[dll]
[:]
[size]
[of]
[tstring]
[:]
[:]
[word]
[=]
[[48]]
[<]
[>]
[std]
[:]
[:]
[string]
[:]
[[40]]
[<]
[>]
[tstring]
[:]
[:]
[cword[16]]
```